# How to effectively balance research, teaching and project work?

Tags: research-process, teaching, productivity, time-management, projects

Starting from the upcoming semester besides my research for the PhD, I will also have to work on a loosely related project (w.r.t. my research), and do teaching as well.

I am overwhelmed from this. It seems that I will never have enough time for the actual research while the project work (50%) and teaching will eat up all my time.

Besides these duties there are also students to supervise, lab to maintain etc.

How do the more experienced ones in AcademiaSE deal / have dealt with such situations?

Comment: Also see [Time management as a TA in mathematics](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58071/time-management-as-a-ta-in-mathematics) (it's more general than it sounds from the title)