# What are the biggest differences transitioning from undergrad to grad school?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, united-states, undergraduate

I was recently accepted into a graduate biophysics program and have a couple questions about what I should expect going into my first semester. While I'm going into a physics PhD, I'd like general advice from any field. I have two specific questions, but welcome any advice that you are willing to share.

What is the biggest thing to overcome/accomplish during your first semester and a graduate student? Looking back, what is something you wish you would have done differently?

Comment: Your second question might be a bit opinion based for the site. For the first question, a big one is learning time management, to juggle classes, teaching and researh. See e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56963/17254

Comment: What I should have done differently: I should have started reading journal articles earlier than I did.  I should have thought about long-range career planning instead of just having fun with my studies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some time during your undergraduate degree, you hopefully moved from the 'repeat back information' paradigm of high school, into the 'integrate information from many sources, analyse it, form your own opinion and defend it' paradigm of university. However, this is not always true for mathematics, physics and similar subjects where there is a right answer that can be constructed.

If you have not made this paradigm shift, this will be a big difference. Because you are now in a research environment. The answer is not necessarily known. What is important is bringing together different types of evidence and working out what is going on.

It may also be true that you have not written an essay during your undergraduate degree (I did only one in my maths degree). This may also be a big transition.

I found my later social sciences undergraduate degree (particularly philosophy courses) to be invaluable in developing good writing skills. A short essay (eg 2000 words) forces you to be articulate arguments really clearly, which is great for research writing.

Answer (score 4):

This may be closed as "primarily opinion based" (especially the second part), but I'll take a whack at it.

> What is the biggest thing to overcome/accomplish during your first semester [as] a graduate student?

Your first 1-2 years is likely taking classes. So, the biggest thing is passing those classes. This should be achievable (though a lot of work), so I'll list also two secondary goals: making friends, and finding an advisor (though this may be a bit early to line up an advisor; every university has a different process).

> Looking back, what is something you wish you would have done differently?

Stayed in my office more. I tended to work on my own at home; while I learned a lot, grad school would have been more fun if I had made more friends and done some of the work collaboratively.

Comment: Also, understand to what extent you are to be pursuing research while taking classes in the first few years. This varies by program.

Answer (score 1):

CULTURE   SHOCK    especially  if  you are transitioning  from  one  state  to  another   state   and  from  one  university  to  another  university.  Even if  you  grew  up  in  two  locations  in  two  different   states  like  i  did.  if  you   are   setting  up   new  "home' in  a  THIRD location,THERE WIL BE CULTURE SHOCK.  The  new  university     and  even the  new  department       college  will have  DIFFERENT   sub  cultures,   so it  may  take  MORE   than one  semester or   quarter  to  adjust.

Your    cumulative  GPA,   weighted  or unweighted, MEANS NOTHING.   You  are  in  an  entirely DIFFERENT   degree  program.  if you  DO NOT   maintain   3.000000 or higher  GPA  on  4.0000000  scale,  you  will  be put  on   academic  probation,  and possibly  not  be  eligible  to  have   teaching  or  research  assistant  ship.   You  are  competing   with  graduate  students   who have  been  there  longer  than you have.  You  are  also at  some point  competing  with FACULTY    members  for professional  recognition.You HAVE  to   able  to  WORK  with  cooperate  with OTHER  pwoplw no matter how  much you like  or  dilike  individual  people. Graduate  school is  TOUGH.   Your  ego is  going  to take  a  beating.  You WILL   be  gossiped  about,  no matter  WHAT you  do..

You also HAVE  to  be  able  communicate  well  in Writing,  in  Academic  English ,  which often  is like   foreign language  to  many people  who  did NOT  grow  up  with parents   who  graduate  college  degrees   who  were  both   teachers  like  i  did.  If you  do NOT know how  to use  a library  and  resources    a  library  has,    i  suggest  you  go  to library  orientation  in  the  first   weeks  of  classes.You HAVE  to  do YOU OWN RESEARCH  now  and  know  HOW  to use   a  search engine.  NO ONE is  going  to  do your  homework  for  you  OR  spoon feed you links  and hyperlinks.

If  ALL you have  right  now  is  self  esteem  with no self  respect,  you may NOT  survive  graduate  school.  Low  esteem   is   survivable.    No  self  respect  may NOT  be  survivable.I  dropped  out  of  graduate  school  for  7  years,  but  I  DID  go  back  to  college  and  i  went  back  to  graduate   school.  i  DID  graduate.  I SURVIVED   graduate  school,  but  only  because  i  was  stubborn  and  i  REFUSED  to  give  up on myself.

I  started   graduate  school in Spring  1981.   i   graduated  from  graduate   school  on  July  29,  2000.   that  was 20 YEARS of  my life.  My mother   died  while  i  was  working  on  My  FIRST  bachelor's  degree.   My  father  died  while  i  was  working  on  my master's  degree..   I  have  THREE  bachelor's   degrees.  The    third  one  had  reason  that  made  sense  to  me   and  it took only  2  years  to  get.

College  staff  can  be   GOLD  mines  of  information   about  faculty members,  staff,   College  and university  services,  like tutoring,and     what  is    available  in   the  local  area  like  medical  doctors,  dentists,  grocery  stores,  restaurants,   bars,  whether a  county  or  town /city  is  "wet"  or  "dry",  drugstores, pharmacies,  and WHERE  things   are.

Congratulations  and  good  luck. Remember how nervous   and  scared you  were  when you  started  college?  Th is  Act   2.  LIFE ins  continuing  education process  and  it NEVER STOPS.   You   will make  mistakes  and you  will have  failures,  small  and   big.  Learn  from  your  mistakes,   Take  responsibility   for  your  actions  and  consequences  of  your  actions,  because you do not  get  do-overs  in  graduate  school.   You either learn,  adapt  and  SURVIVE,  or you  don't.

Comment: WHY the random CAPITALISED words?

Comment: That's my online  writing   a  style.  i  am used  to  answering  questions   on  Yahoo  Answers. I   am  addicted  to  Yahoo  Answers,  and  i  do NOT like  Reddit.  The  capitalized  words  are  for  emphasis...  The  capitalization   is NOT  random.  it  just  SEEMS   to  be   random.   I  cannot  read  your  mind  and you  cannot  read my mind.

Comment: @CarolMiller1600 Perhaps you could use _italics_ or **bold face** instead of using CAPITALISED words for emphasis. That would fit more in the overall style of this site.

Comment: " if you DO NOT maintain 3.000000 or higher GPA on 4.0000000 scale, you will be put on academic probation" Many schools have GPA requirements in grad school, but the specifics vary a lot by school and program; this precise policy is far from universal.

Comment: @CarolMiller1600 - Welcome to StackExchange.  I have a suggestion for you (in addition to steering clear of all caps as the lizard said).  Proofread.  Write your draft, then step away and do something else for at least ten minutes, then come back and read your draft in the area below the box where you type in your post.  It will show up in formatted form down there and that is easier to proofread effectively.  Also, make sure your browser is spell-checking as you type. Final tip: you can learn formatting tricks by pretending to edit someone else's post (i.e. read *their* markdown).

Comment: Why would we assume that someone good enough to get into a phd program in physics would even need to worry about his/her gpa dropping below the acceptable level? I'm sure he/she is a great student and will do fine. Stress and panic over grades is not the way to get through this. Work hard and be positive.